# Twilio truncating the query string in callback URL

Tags: callback, twilio, query-string

I am passing a callback URL with a query string when sending an SMS message.  I checked the debugger logs when the callback didn't seem to be working.  I see "Error - 11200 HTTP retrieval failure" for the callback URL and it seems from the log details that the callback URL that I am passing is truncated after "?".  The query string I am passing is not part of the URL and hence Twilio is getting the above error.

How to pass query string to Twilio's callback API?

Answer (score 0):

We were actually having the same issue in our project. Looks like Twilio trims any query string parameters. Our workaround was to add any additional data to our route:

```
//original route:
GET /user/{userid}?myParam={myParam}
GET user/123?myParam=456

//modified route
GET /user/{userid}/{myParam}
GET user/123/456
```

However this means that you will need to update your server code to look for path parameters instead of query strings.